# Is it possible to use cv2.HoughCircles Function for multiple images?

Tags: python, opencv

Most the sources provide their codes that only detect circles for one image. Is it possible to detect circles for multiple images? If yes, how should I do? If no, why it is impossible?

```
for img in os.listdir(path):  
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img)) 
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_array,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10,param1=50,param2=12,minRadius=0,maxRadius=10)
```

and when I run this code, I get this error. Could anyone help explain what this means?

> error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp:1736: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function 'cv::HoughCircles'

Comment: Your example code already contains the answer? You are detecting circles in the images in whole folder.

Comment: oh sorry for mistake and i just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message is telling you either your image is empty, or it is not grayscale, or it is not an OpenCV image. Most likely its the second one. HoughCircles function only works for grayscale images, you need to convert your image to gray before using it:

```
for img in os.listdir(path):  
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img)) 
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_gray,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10,param1=50,param2=12,minRadius=0,maxRadius=10)
```